# Counting the number of instructions in an instruction set

Tags: computer-architecture

> An imaginary processor has the following hardware 
>   specification:
>
> - 8bit data bus
> - 12bit address bus
> - 32 × 8bit general purpose registers e.g. `S0` – `S1F`
>
> Briefly describe what bit fields are required within an instruction to encode 
>   the following functionality:
>
> 1. 56 different instructions
> 2. Register addressing e.g. `ADD S0, S1`, add the contents of 
>      register `S1` to register `S0`, store the result in register `S0`.
> 3. Immediate addressing e.g. `ADDI S0, 10`, add the constant
>      10 (base 16) to register `S0`, store the result in register `S0`.
> 4. Absolute addressing e.g. `ADDA S0, 100`, add the data 
>      stored in external memory address 100 (base 16) to register `S0`, store the 
>      result in register `S0`
> 5. If the processor uses a fixed length instruction format, 
>      briefly describe how many bits are required to represent an 
>      instruction and the bit fields used.

For (1), I know it's $\log_2 56$ round up to 6 bits
but for (2), I know the answer is 6bits+5bits+5bits, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: What are your own ideas on this? This is *not* the site to go to for "do my homework for me, so I don't have to learn anything" type answers.

Comment: I see no reason to put the question on hold as "unclear" - it is very clear what is being asked.

Comment: @RanG., that's the standard reason used for problem dumps that seems to be asking for help understanding (e.g., understanding how to approach the problem) but that don't show their work or what they tried in enough detail to diagnose the source of their misunderstanding.  See http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/772/755 and http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/779/755 and http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/471/755.  As vonbrand hints, the author is expected to show their own thoughts and what they tried (so we have a better chance of being able to help them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An "add" instruction (e.g., ADD S0 S1B) must have 3 parts of information:

1. which instruction to do ("ADD")
2. Which is the input register (S0)
3. Which is the output register (S1B)

How many bits does each part take? Well, you correctly answered that the first part is 6 bit. Can you see why the second and third parts take 5 bits each?

For the other parts of the question, try to split to the information the instruction must have, and analyze the amount of bits each part takes, under the definitions of the specific machine in use.

Comment: Ok so i tried my best this is what i think now:
(b) ADD is 6bits because of (a),but why i don't know, i always thought Opcode bits depends on the hardware? and S0 and S1 are each 5bits due to log2(32) from 32*8 GPR, what does 32*8 GPR actaully mean, is 32 registers or 32bits data*8 addresses?

(c)ADDI=6bits, S0=5bits, 10(base16)is 8bits because each heaxadecimal is 4bits, so overall 19bits

Comment: (d) same idea as (c), but then for (e), i have no idea what it is trying to ask

Comment: (a) yes, opcode bits depend on the hardware.  You are designing the hardware.  32 x 8bit GPRs means 32 registers, each of which can hold 8 bits of data.  (e): take the maximum of (b), (c), (d), then explain where everything goes.